# Fast open source c++ memory pool

Tags: open-source, c++, memory-management

What are the best open source memory pools available in c++?
I do not want thread safety as application will be single threaded. I primary goal is fast allocation and de-allocation. Bit of more than required memory usage is allowed and more initialization time is ok.

In detail, when i say `obj = pool.alloc()`, I should get the memory for `Object` from `pool<Object>` memory as fast as possible. When I say `pool.free(obj)`, memory pointed by `obj` (which belongs to pool) must be freed immediately and return the memory to object pool. These operations should not involve any locks. Internally, pool could take bit more memory to manage `Objects` free/allocated instanaces.

Comment: Do you mean allocators / managers of memory within a contiguous pool? Can you specify what capabilities you actually need? Also, is only the openness of the source important to you, or don't you maybe also want the ability to copy and use the code yourself?

Comment: @einpoklum: edited the question.

Comment: ... and now I'd like someone to answer as well :-)

Comment: The question is still unclear. Memory is never thread-safe, so this is either a misunderstanding or at least does not help. Next, you can't allocate memory faster than the operating system itself. If the C++ heap manager is too slow for you, just use VirtualAlloc().

Comment: @ThomasWeller : You are right, memory is never thread-safe. I am trying to allocate the memory from Pool and not from Operating system. pool.alloc is function of object pool. Now object memory pool does the malloc/new only once during the initialization to allocate memory for millions of the objects. And later only if pool gets full. Pool.delete or  Pool.free frees memory in the pool and does not free memory from memory manager.

Answer (score 2):

I found boost `object_pool` to be useful. Boost `object_pool` could be used within single thread. It does not take any lock while allocating memory or freeing memory to the pool.
There is variant of this `singleton_pool` which is thread-safe memory pool and multiple threads could access `singleton_pool` simultaneously in concurrent environment.
Will post if I find any other open source object memory pool.